# databricks autoloader not working with CSV

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

My environment is "Unity" enabled.

i am trying to ingest/read a CSV file via autoloader and save it as delta table.

code is pretty simple, but i am getting error.

```
df_current = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
            .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
            .option("multiLine", "true")\
            .option("header", "true")\
            .option('escape', "\"")\
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", f"{base_loc_out}/{channel_name}/schema/{filename}")\
            .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")\
            .load(channel_file.path)\
            .writeStream \
            .format("delta")\
            .option("checkpointLocation", f"{base_loc_out}/{channel_name}/checkpoint/{filename}") \
            .trigger(availableNow=True)\
            .toTable(f"{catalog_name}.{schema_name}.{filename}")
            df_current.awaitTermination()
            print(f"number of rows read => {df_current.lastProgress['numInputRows']}, number of rows written => {df_current.lastProgress['sink']['numOutputRows']}")
```

I am getting error =>

```
com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesException: Cannot infer schema when the input path `abfss://***************/employees.csv` is empty. Please try to start the stream when there are files in the input path, or specify the schema.
```

although file is not empty, as i can see following code working absolutely fine.

```
df_current = spark.read\
                .option("header","true")\
                .option("inferSchema","true")\
                .option("multiLine", "true")\
                .option('escape', "\"")\
                .option('delimiter', ',')\
                    .csv(channel_file.path)
            df_current.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"{catalog_name}.{schema_name}.{filename}")
```

So file is not an issue. but somehow autloader is not ready to infer schema from file.

infact i am able to run

```
dbutils.fs.head("abfss://****************/employees.csv")
```

data looks like

```
empid,empName,salary,dep
1,mani,6000,IT
2,Bharath,2000,Payroll
3,Vamsi,3000,IT
4,Nikhil,1000,Payroll
5,mahesh,2500,HR
6,srinu,3500,Payroll
7,nag,4500,IT
8,neeraj,1500,HR
9,dsp,10000,HR
10,deeraj,4500,IT
```

Comment: where the `channel_file.path` is located? is it UC-governed location?

Comment: yes it is Unity governed loc. also both running and non-running version of code is part of same notebook, same workspace.

Comment: Can you try hard coding the path `channel_file.path` ? Also is it possible that the file name is appended to the path ?

Comment: i can try that, but then the very next code snipped should not have worked. also stacktrace does print the file name. so it is not empty or corrupted path. I did use same path from stack trace in dbutils, and i was able to print file content.